# Is it possible to alter a table when you install a new plugin in the install.xml in moodle?

Tags: moodle

Basicly, I need to add a new column in the course table.

And I do not know how to make this change for then export the module to others schools

Without to execute the "alter table" query in each database in each school

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fresh install, you can use install.php to alter core tables like the course table. Install.php is called immediately after install.xml.

First get the add field code

Go to site admin -> development -> xmldb editor

Load and edit lib/db

Then edit the course table and add the new field. **Don't save it though.**

Then go to view php code, select add field with your new field then view.

Copy the code without the upgrade bit at the start and end. Then add this to `local/yourplugin/db/install.php`, so you should have something like this:

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

function  xmldb_local_yourplugin_install() {
    global $DB;

    $dbman = $DB->get_manager();

    // Define field newfield to be added to course.
    $table = new xmldb_table('course');
    $field = new xmldb_field('newfield', XMLDB_TYPE_INTEGER, '1', null, null, null, null, 'cacherev');

    // Conditionally launch add field newfield.
    if (!$dbman->field_exists($table, $field)) {
        $dbman->add_field($table, $field);
    }
}
```